# How to copy rows from one dataframe to another dataframe based on the index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I have a problem with '`loc'` and`'iloc'` .So I have a list and a data frame, I want to check if the data in list and date in data frame of a column is matching. if matching I need to copy it to a new data frame. I am half way but I don't know how to copy the rows from a data frame to new one based on the index. How do we do that?

Code:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2,3,5,6], 'col2': [3, 4,5,6,7]}
cols = list(df.columns)
df1=pd.DataFrame(columns=cols) 
lst=['1','2']
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
for index,v in df['col1'].iteritems():
    for l in lst:
        if l == v:
            df1 = df.loc[index]
```

which gives nothing(empty data frame):

```
col1    col2
```

Actual output:

```
df1 =
   col1 col2
0   1   3
1   2   4
```

Comment: You have data type problems.  lst is a string, your default index in df is an integer. l will not equal v.  change to `lst=[1,2]`

Comment: loc is using label based index, iloc is using integer position based indexing.  Confusion happens mostly because with the default range index of a dataframe, the indexing are integer matching exactly the position based of the index, thus either will work.

Comment: aside from the data type problem, try `isin` and boolean indexing `df.loc[df['col1'].isin(lst)]`.

Comment: @ScottBoston Thanks for the explanation .Yes, it did

Comment: @QuangHoang Your approach was simple.Thanks alot :) helped me alot